# Can the pg gem be used to import database dump (.sql) files?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, rake

We've got some utility rake tasks for cloning postgres databases from Heroku to local development machines for testing with "real" data. They tend to run the import with shell commands of `pg_restore`, e.g.

```
sh 'pg_restore --verbose --clean --create --no-owner -h localhost <dbname> <filename>'
```

Can this sort of postgres operation be achieved with the pg gem (already in place for Rails) or is our punt-to-shell operation here really the best way to do it? I haven't found anything promising in [the documentation](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are commands that exist outside of the postgres library, I don't believe there is a way to accomplish this with the pg gem.  However, according to the heroku docs for what you are trying to accomplish, it looks like you are doing it the way they [recommend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

```
heroku pgbackups:capture
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

Comment: Ah, that's a good reason I wouldn't have found functions in pg.